# System of linear equations in matlab with 2 ways but can't get same results

Tags: matlab, linear-equation

I'm trying to solve a system of 4 linear equations in Matlab with two ways
First:

```
A = [5,2,3,4;2,6,1,9;6,3,1,5;2,4,7,9];
B = [7;11;5;3];
X = [A\B]';
```

With the result:

```
X =  0.5556   17.4667    4.4889  -11.0444
```

Second:

```
[x,y,z,w] = solve('5*x+2*y+3*z+4*w-7','2*x+6*y+z+9*w-11','6*x+3*y+z+5*w-5','2*x+4*y+7*z+9*w-3')
```

With result:

```
X = -497/45, Y=5/9,  Z=262/15, W=202/45
```

As you can see the results on the second way aren't in the correct order. I googled the equations and found that the first order is the correct one.

Has anyone an idea of what's going on and how to solve it?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Specify the order of the unknowns when you call `solve`:

```
>> syms x y z w %// define symbolic variables (unknowns)
>> [x0,y0,z0,w0] = solve('5*x+2*y+3*z+4*w-7',...
                         '2*x+6*y+z+9*w-11',...
                         '6*x+3*y+z+5*w-5',...
                         '2*x+4*y+7*z+9*w-3',...
                          x, y, z, w)
x0 =
5/9
y0 =
262/15
z0 =
202/45
w0 =
-497/45
```

By the way, once you have defined `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` as symbolic variables you can avoid the quotation marks:

```
>> [x0,y0,z0,w0] = solve(5*x+2*y+3*z+4*w-7,...
                         2*x+6*y+z+9*w-11,...
                         6*x+3*y+z+5*w-5,...
                         2*x+4*y+7*z+9*w-3,...
                         x, y, z, w)
x0 =
5/9
y0 =
262/15
z0 =
202/45
w0 =
-497/45
```

Comment: I tried that too, but the results I get are the same as before.

Comment: Yeah, but still the same.

Comment: Just to make sure: copy and paste this: `clear all; syms x y z w; [x0,y0,z0,w0] = solve(5*x+2*y+3*z+4*w-7, 2*x+6*y+z+9*w-11, 6*x+3*y+z+5*w-5, 2*x+4*y+7*z+9*w-3,x, y, z, w)`

Comment: Again same as before.

Comment: @user2466795 - I'm able to get what Luis Mendo has posted.  I think there's something wrong on your end.  In the most **extreme** case, close MATLAB, restart it, then put in what Luis Mendo told you in his comment to you above.

Comment: I still couldn't get the correct result after restarting matlab, but i tried this:
S = solve(5*x+2*y+3*z+4*w-7, 2*x+6*y+z+9*w-11, 6*x+3*y+z+5*w-5, 2*x+4*y+7*z+9*w-3,x, y, z, w);
x = S.x
y = S.y
z = S.z
w = S.w

end it worked!